# How can I get the value of array outside the function - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function:

```
  var latLong = promise.then(function(response) {
       for(var j = 0; j <= response.length - 1; j++) {      
            coordenadas.push( {lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng});   
        }
        return coordenadas;
    });
```

[I got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKhjg.png)

How can I access the **lat** and **lng** variables outside this function?

Tku so much

Comment: `coordenadas[i].lat`, `coordenadas[i].lng` where i is the index of the array, e.g. `coordenadas[0].lat`

Comment: which function? and what is the specific index value you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `coordenadas` (binding to UI etc), you need to bind it to `$scope` (or something being watched).  Simply returning only allows you to continue the promise chain (which you are not doing).

Something like this would work (in a controller that depends on `$scope`):

```
    promise.then(function(response) {
       for(var j = 0; j <= response.length - 1; j++) {      
            coordenadas.push( {lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng});   
        }
        $scope.coordenadas = coordenadas;
    });
```

If you want to use the returned promise in another place.  Then you would have to continue to chain:

```
var latLong = promise.then(function(response) {
       for(var j = 0; j <= response.length - 1; j++) {      
            coordenadas.push( {lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng});   
        }
        return coordenadas;
    });

latLong.then(function(coordenadas) {
    console.log(coordenadas;
});
```

Comment: I want to use coordenadas in another function Davin.

Comment: @SamyrAbdo ok, edited now to show using the returned promise.